# My ubuntu is hanging

Tags: keyboard

Actually, l think this hanging problem in my ubuntu 14.04 is related to keyboard. Because, some times when I press any key, save file window is being opened. Now, it has been a serious problem for me to handle it.So, please tell me what should l do to get rid of this

Comment: It's a common problem when the keyboard is very dirty and keys are sticky. I'd suggest to use compressed air to clean it (be careful when doing it) and then test again.

Comment: Most keyboards let you take the cover off so you can clean it more easily, e. g. by blowing compressed air under the keys from the side or sticking a brush under them from the side.